# anchor tag href not linking with div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mean

I am trying to link an an anchor to a div with in the same page. I did the following:

```
<a class="chev" href="#yes"> 
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</a>
...
..
..

<div id="yes"> some content </div>
```

However, when the link is clicked, the page isn't taking me to the div. Here is the error message I have been getting from the console:

Uncaught Error: [$location:ihshprfx] Invalid url "hostname/#yes", missing hash prefix "#!".

I did look at some other solutions, but none of them work.

any ideas?

Comment: You have some JavaScript interfering, but you haven't provided enough code to tell what.

Comment: Why on earth is this tagged `mean`?

Comment: What kind of JS interference are you talking about. The view does not have any imbedded JS. However, it is wrapped in an angular controller.

Comment: The kind where JavaScript is intercepting the link and trying to do something with the URL. Wrapping it in an angular controller sounds like a pretty major bit of JavaScript interference.

Comment: The error is saying missing hash prefix !#, which is not clear.

Comment: how would you get rid of the javascript interference in this context?

Comment: Find the code that is doing the interference. Learn how it worked. Then either use its existing features to avoid it or edit it.

Comment: @user3681587, have you seen my answer below and tried what I suggest?  It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that since you are doing this inside an Angular controller, Angular thinks that the #yes anchor is referring to a specific route, *not* just a plain old anchor within the page.

If I remember correctly, specifying `target="_self"` on the link will tell Angular to just leave it alone and it will just behave like any normal link.

Try this:

```
<a class="chev" href="#yes" target="_self"> 
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</a>
...
..
..

<div id="yes"> some content </div>
```

More information here: http://eli.eliandlyndi.com/2013/08/26/navigate-urls-angular-application-target_self/

Comment: Hi @HaukurHaf , I stuck with same issue but even after including `target="_self"` my problem remains same.

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me like you are doing it backwards. I'm pretty sure that you can only jump to other anchor tags. Try changing the div to an anchor, or put an anchor above it.

```
<a class="chev" href="#yes"> 
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</a>
...
..
..
<a id='yes'></a>
<div> some content </div>
```

Comment: "I'm pretty sure that you can only jump to other anchor tags." — That was true in HTML 3.2. Since 1997 you can jump to any element with an id.

Comment: _“I'm pretty sure that you can only jump to other anchor tags”_ – that’s wrong, +any_ element with an `id` is a valid target.

Comment: Probably have some JS that is interfering with the jump them